# "If you say so": Dismissive agreement

Tags: word-choice, word-requests, equivalent-phrase

I would like to know some ways to agree in a non-committal or dismissive way. For instance, in English, we have:

> If you say so.
>
> Is that so? (with a flat intonation)
>
> Really? (flat intonation)
>
> Whatever you say.

In Chinese, I'm a bit at a loss. "Is that so?" and "Really?" work fine translated literally (`是吗？`, `真的吗？`, similar intonation). Beyond that, I'm drawing a blank. Furthermore, it seems difficult to look these things up since the **tone** is important and **not the literal meaning**.

Comment: A possible translation is "你說了算", but it is more literal than your example.

Comment: The one I said most is "随你便".

Comment: What about this scenario?
A: 能不能再加一小时班? 明天绝对不会再让你加班了 (Could you work overtime again for an extra hour? I won't ask you tomorrow, I promise.)
B: 既然你已经这么说了,那我还能说什么呢? (If you say so)

Answer (score 8):

A few that are used the most in my surroundings:

- 好吧 (in a helpless tone) = Fine.
- 随便 = whatever.
- 都行 = whatever.
- 无所谓 = I don't care.
- 你说[X]就[X]吧 = If you say so.

Answer (score 5):

It will be easier to answer this question if a more specific scenario is given.

Let me try to suggest one:

> A: 能不能再加一小时班? 明天绝对不会再让你加班了 (Could you work overtime again for an extra hour? I won't ask you tomorrow, I promise.)
>
> B: 好吧... 既然你已经这么说了, 那我还能说什么呢? (O--k--ay--, If you say so... :-| )

If you simply want to say "O--k--ay--" in Chinese, with special tones, you can do it like this:

> B: 唉~~~ (extend the final sound "Sigh" **to express disappointment** ) 好吧, 好吧, 好吧... (repeat saying "Okay" to **show decent impatience in your tone** .),

---

For other possible scenarios, please refer to the following links and examples:

1. [10 ways to express your "dismissive feelings" in English (10 种英文表达说出你的无所谓)](http://blog.nciku.cn/blog/zh/?p=786)
2. [Some ways to express "whatever" (“无所谓”的几种表达)](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/language_tips/suvival/2011-11/02/content_14024959.htm)

In detail:

- 对……无碍,不要紧 ~ be ok (fine) with

> Whatever you think is fine with me. 随你怎么想,我无所谓.

- 不在乎, 不感兴趣 ~ give a damn

> 永远用于否定形式, He couldn't give a damn whether he passes the exam or not. 他对考试及格与否满不在乎.

- 随你的便(按自己的意愿行事). ~ suit yourself / as you wish / if you want.

> a) You don't want to join the club? Oh well, suit yourself. 你不愿意参加俱乐部是吗? 那好,随你的便吧
>
> b) As for your departments plan, you can change as you wish. 至于你们部门的计划,你愿意怎么改就怎么改吧.

- 听你的 / 由你决定 / 取决于你. ~ it's up to you.

> So if you really want class to make a difference in your life, it's up to you. 所以如果你真的想通过这门课改变生活,一切取决于你.

- 我不在乎. ~ I don't care.

> I don't care what she thinks. 我不管她怎么想.

- 管他呢 / 爱咋咋地 / 该怎么着就怎么着吧 ~ whatever

> I totally have no idea how to file my tax return, whatever. 我完全不知道该怎么报税,唉,该怎么着就怎么着吧/爱咋咋地. (在中文口语里, **"咋"可以跟"怎么"互换**)

- 没什么好说的/没啥好说的. ~ Nothing to say.

> I have nothing to say about the government's stimulation plan. 对政府的刺激计划, 我没什么/没啥好说的. (在中文口语里, **"啥"可以跟"什么"互换**)

- 那又怎样? ~ So what?
- 没什么了不起. ~ No Big deal.
- 怎么都行. ~ Anything will do.

Comment: BTW(whether my answer is relevant or not): When people speak to me with this feelings, i usually feel disappointed, even frustrated. I sometimes response to my friends in this way, and I tell from their words(after my response) that they also don't like it. :)

Comment: Very complete answer. A couple things: 1. 随你的便 can also be 随便你 in oral chinese. 2. I'm sort of especially interested in scenarios where people express opinions which I disagree with, they expect me to agree or say something, and I don't really want to have a real argument.